# How to grep in parallel with multiple matching pattern?

Tags: r, bash, parallel-processing, grep

I'm trying to make a search in a big file for a matching sequence

```
genotype.phased="~/Desktop/test.txt.gz"
selected.chr.pos = c("NC761570.1_123", "NC761572.1_425634")
cmd = paste("gzcat ", genotype.phased, " | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E ", 
     paste0("'",paste0(selected.chr.pos, collapse = "|"),"'"), "{}")
cmd
```

gives

```
gzcat  ~/Desktop/test.txt.gz  | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E  'NC761570.1_123|NC761572.1_425634' {}
```

But this is not working as the pipe `|` seems to need an escape like this `\|`:

```
gzcat  ~/Desktop/test.txt.gz  | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E  'NC761570.1_123\|NC761572.1_425634' {}
```

When I run the above command, it does work.

It's easy to add this by hand, but I have ~200 search patterns and thus would be nice to have a way to generate this sequence.

The problem is that when I use

```
paste0(selected.chr.pos, collapse = "\|")
```

I get

```
Error: '\|' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\|"
```

And I can't find a way to add a `\`

So how could I generate the search pattern (with the `\|`) to run inside a terminal but within R, like so:

```
sub.line = system(command.paste, # Will search the chr position combo 
                  intern = TRUE) # Report the data inside R so it can be used
```

The only way I found so far was to write the `search.chr.pos.sep` object to a file and then to run an AWK command in the terminal.

```
write.table(search.chr.pos.sep, 
            file = "~/Desktop/test.file.txt",
            row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F)
```

In the terminal

```
awk '{gsub(/\|/,"\\|")}8' ~/Desktop/test.file.txt > ~/Desktop/test.file2.txt
```

Then, going back to R...

read.table(file = "~/Desktop/test.file2.txt")$V1

but I get this:

```
"LR761574.1_33200027\\|LR761574.1_33199177\\|CADCXG010001475.1_2568\\|LR761581.1_19425299\\|CADCXG010000358.1_42898\\|LR761589.1_7857902\\|LR761589.1_7858330\\|CADCXG010001051.1_9141\\|CADCXG010000646.1_23583\\|CADCXG010000765.1_19030\\|CADCXG010000453.1_1949\\|CADCXG010000823.1_12489\\|CADCXG010000233.1_340474\\|LR761582.1_1161490\\|CADCXG010000244.1_155109\\|LR761573.1_10994013\\|CADCXG010000319.1_24716\\|CADCXG010000233.1_267363\\|LR761581.1_19434057\\|LR761576.1_37364972\\|LR761570.1_96001606\\|CADCXG010000714.1_7341\\|LR761585.1_16108831\\|CADCXG010000593.1_26574\\|CADCXG010000423.1_31741\\|CADCXG010000244.1_137955\\|CADCXG010000257.1_49433\\|CADCXG010000271.1_64738\\|CADCXG010000369.1_36917\\|CADCXG010000629.1_9820\\|LR761572.1_46021459\\|LR761583.1_17465385\\|CADCXG010000394.1_28503\\|CADCXG010000459.1_26479\\|LR761589.1_7863214\\|CADCXG010000311.1_35962\\|LR761587.1_13250670"
```

with the `\\|` and not the `\|`!

Comment: You may need to escape `paste(c('a', 'b'), collapse = "\\|")`

Comment: So I've tried that, but it doesn't work and gives me a `/bin/bash: NC761572.1_425634: command not found grep: trailing backslash (\)` so I don't know how I can have only one \.

Comment: you can try something like: 'selected.chr.pos = gsub("([^[:alnum:]])", "\\\\\\1", selected.chr.pos)
cmd = paste("gzcat ", genotype.phased, " | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E ", 
     paste0("'",paste0(selected.chr.pos, collapse = "|"),"'"), "{}")
cmd'

Comment: Mmm. Interesting, but I got `gzcat  ~/Desktop/test.txt.gz  | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E  'NC761570\\.1\\_123|NC761572\\.1\\_425634' {}` as an output. But what I'm looking for is `gzcat  ~/Desktop/test.txt.gz  | parallel -j8 --pipe --block 300M --cat grep -E  'NC761570.1_123\|NC761572.1_425634' {}`. See how the \| is only between the `NC761570.1_123` and `NC761572.1_425634`. Basically, between characters_numbers \| characters_numbers. My `NC761570.1_123`sometimes start with other sequences (e.g. LC, NW, CAD..., etc.)

Comment: I guess parallel can use pipes, but when looking into the `grep` search pattern, it requires \| or `parallel` tries to execute the `NC761572.1_425634` as a piped command

Comment: This command would work: `command.paste = paste("gzcat ", genotype.phased, " | grep -E ", paste0("'",paste0(selected.chr.pos, collapse = "|"),"'"))` with output `gzcat  ~/Desktop/test.txt.gz  | grep -E  'NC761570.1_123|NC761572.1_425634'` but it doesn't use `parallel` (see now how between the 2 `NC###`, there is only a | and not a \|). The cool thing with `parallel` is that I can split up the file in smaller chunk to look for the grep pattern which appears to be much faster.

Comment: What about big data tools. Instead or martian bash scripts, you could use sql queries to search whatever you need

Comment: Interesting, but I don't know how I could make this possible with the `"~/Desktop/test.txt.gz"`